# Can't display Json from api for a specific item

Tags: angular

I want to display a specific student by ID. And this is the error it return me with: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. I have managed to display a full list but this occur when I try to go for single one.

My component

```
export class StudentIDComponent implements OnInit {
  id: any;
  url: any;
  studentID;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private sqlService: StudentServerListService
  ) { }

  getStudentID() {
    return this.http.get("https://localhost:44303/api/student/" + this.route.snapshot.params['studentId']);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['studentId']);
    //this.studentID = this.sqlService.getOne();
    this.studentID = this.getStudentID();
    this.url = console.log("https://localhost:44303/api/student/" + this.route.snapshot.params['studentId']);
  }
}
```

My HTML

```
<h3>Student by ID</h3>
<div *ngFor="let key of studentID | async">
  <h2>
    {{key.studentId}}. xcxcx
    {{key.studentName}}
  </h2>
</div>
<h1>sdsdssd</h1>
```

My sample Json

> {
>       "subjectSS": [],
>       "studentId": 3,
>       "studentName": "Long" }

Comment: can you print out in .html  `{{ studentID | async | json }}` and show us output here?

Comment: If you want to display a single record ngFor not required. Just display it directly since your json has object values.

Comment: @Mridul I also think about that is hard for me since most of the turtorial of Angular on the internet is just about list and stuff. Could you send me a link with example of something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe rather than using | async.

On the component

```
 subscribeStudentID() {
   this.http.get("https://localhost:44303/api/student/" +  this.route.snapshot.params['studentId'])
   .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.studentID = data;
   });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['studentId']);
    //this.studentID = this.sqlService.getOne();
    this.subscribeStudentID();
    this.url = console.log("https://localhost:44303/api/student/" +        this.route.snapshot.params['studentId']);
  }
```

On the HTML

```
<h3>Student by ID</h3>
<div *ngIf="studentID">
  <h2>
    {{studentID.studentId}}. xcxcx
    {{studentID.studentName}}
  </h2>
</div>
<h1>sdsdssd</h1>
```

There are other solutions but for me this is the cleanest, also you can try to use a get method for studentID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an object, not array. So [use keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<div *ngFor="let key of studentID | async | keyvalue">
  <h2>
    {{key.studentId}}. xcxcx
    {{key.studentName}}
  </h2>
</div>
```

[A stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/keyvalue-pipe-qmt58n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It won't show me the detail instead it's just some random dot that I put on purpose to identify how many thing will be show: https://imgur.com/a/f3QUNWL